# Unity: "NetworkBehaviour" is missing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to run the sample project from google AR Core [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/quickstart-android).

There is error in the sample code.

> error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'NetworkBehaviour' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
using GoogleARCore;
using GoogleARCore.CrossPlatform;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

/// <summary>
/// A Controller for the Anchor object that handles hosting and resolving the Cloud Anchor.
/// </summary>
public class AnchorController : NetworkBehaviour
{
    ....
```

I am using the `2020.1.0f1` version. What can I do to fix this? It is said deprecated while the new replacement is still under development.

Deprecated but cannot be used and there is no replacement at the moment. I am stuck here.

Comment: I recommend using Mirror. It's the same API with many extensions.

Answer (score 8):

For Unity 2020, I used Window > Package Manager and pressed the + (plus) sign:
Add Package from git URL and set it to:

- com.unity.multiplayer-hlapi

and

- com.unity.xr.legacyinputhelpers

as it was recommended here:
https://medium.com/@jeffreymlynch/where-are-the-missing-preview-packages-in-unity-2020-3ad0935e4193

Answer (score 2):

use Window > Package Manager to install the Multiplayer HLAPI and XR Legacy Input Helpers packages.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind the `Multiplayer HLAPI` and `XR Legacy Input Helpers` only available in unity version < 2020. In 2020 version, there is no option to install them both. The solution is I just downgrade the version into 2019.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Mirror, type:
using Mirror;

at the top of script